# Analog audio device not available in Sound settings

Tags: sound, 13.10, pulseaudio

Ubuntu 13.10 installed fresh (not upgraded) on an Intense PC (Analog and S/PDIF share same jack)

Analog audio output used to work just fine, but now does not appear in sound settings anymore; only "Digital Output (S/PDIF) Built-in Audio" is shown. 
I never used S/PDIF output; maybe it works, but it's currently useless for me - If I choose it, nothing goes to the speakers.

`aplay -L` shows

```
default
    Playback/recording through the PulseAudio sound server
sysdefault:CARD=PCH
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC888 Analog
    Default Audio Device
front:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC888 Analog
    Front speakers
(...)
```

playing to these devices with `aplay -D <device> /usr/share/sounds/alsa/Front_Center.wav`:

- "default" - everything is silent.
- "sysdefault" - sound plays to the speakers normally (HW is OK!).
- For any other device I get an error

  ```
  aplay: set_params:1239: Channels count non available
  ```

I've found a partial workaround: I installed pavucontrol, and from its configuration tab I can choose "Analog Stereo Sutput" and then all applications play audio normally (including aplay to "default"). But, there is still no "analog output" option in the system settings (only S/PDIF), and no audio control in the menu bar; I have to do everything from pavucontrol.